# How to add error handling for ansible shell module with pipes?

Tags: shell, rhel, pipe, ansible

I have an Ansible shell module like below.

```
- name: "Verifying file"
  shell: cat filename | grep something | tail -1 | awk '{print $4}' 
  register: hname
```

How to do error handling like if one pipe fails to get input, it has to exit ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using  `set builtin` with `pipefail` solved the issue.

```
- name: "Verifying file"
  shell: "set -o pipefail && cat filename | grep something | tail -1 | awk '{print $4}'"
  register: hname
```

This will `exit` the task even if one `pipe` fails to get input.